# global key press listener

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

Right now I try to write program to measure my programming efficienty, ex. what ammount of time I spend on writing Code. To do that I need to listen to keyboard input, globaly for whole system not only window with focus. 
Is there any way to listen globaly for key events (ex. libs), or I need to fight with kbd source?

Comment: what's wrong with a stopwatch?

Comment: i mean, if you want to time how long you code for, why not use a stopwatch? A real-world physical stopwatch that a sports trainer might use.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some of the existing software which does this.  For example keyloggers.  MAybe this one would be useful: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the window one is currently typing in have the focus? You're saying "not only the window in focus" but no typing will be happening with a window not in focus, yes?

Anyways, I recently implemented a threading base approach for a Silverlight app, and used a custom StopWatch class to check the time span while typing is actually going on. You'll have to set a default timeout period for the time between keydown and keyup events to know when one is not currently typing. If interested in some code example, hit me up:

dwhitten15@hotmail.com

Ciao,

David

Comment: This is where I sign you up for spam with that email. :)